# Angular-cli task to modify index.html

Tags: angular-cli

Is there a way to modify index.html file after angular-cli build process? I'm working on ng2+ app.

The thing is that angular-cli adds bundle scripts (like vendor.bundle.js) into the end of body tag. But I need different behaviour.

Can I do that somehow?